# Help with infimum of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I was looking at an exercise in which I have to find the supremum and infimum of a set , and I need some help with the infumum part. The set is :

$$A = \left\{ \frac{n^2+2n+3}{4n^2+2n} \; \middle| \; n \text{ a natural number (different from 0)} \right\}$$

If we consider the function $f(x) =  \frac{x^2 +2x +3}{4x^2 +2x}$ we have a decreasing function from $x>0$ and therefore $f(n)$ is a decreasing function. Since the set $A$ is the range of $f(n)$ for the indicated $n$’s, its clear that the upper bound is $1$, and the lower bound is $1/4$ (the value of the limit of $f(n)$ when $n$ goes to infinity).

So, for the supremum part :

Let $M$ be an upper bound. We want to show that $1\leq\ M$. Suppose $1 \gt\ M$
For def of upper bound we have $f(n) \leq \ M$. So $ f(n) \leq\ M \lt\ 1$. If $n=1$, then $ 1\leq\ M \lt\ 1 $ and this is a contradiction caused by saying that $1 \gt\ M$ , therefore $1 \leq\ M$ and$ 1$ is supremum by definition of supremum.

Infimum proof : Here I don't know how to use the fact that the limit of $f(n)$ when $n$ goes to infinity is $1/4$. Can you give me some ideas please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\sup A=1$ because $1\in A$ and because $a\in A\implies a\leqslant1$ (so, in fact, $1=\max A$).

On the other hand, if $a\in A$, then $a>\frac14$, and therefore $\frac14$ is a lower bound of $A$. Now, take $r>\frac14$. and let $\varepsilon=r-\frac14$. Since $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that\begin{align}n\geqslant N\implies\left|\frac14-\frac{n^2+2n+3}{4n^2+2n}\right|<\varepsilon&\iff\frac{n^2+2n+3}{4n^2+2n}-\frac14<\varepsilon=r-\frac14\\&\iff\frac{n^2+2n+3}{4n^2+2n}<r,\end{align}and so $\frac{N^2+2N+3}{4N^2+2N}<r$. But $\frac{N^2+2N+3}{4N^2+2N}\in A$. Therefore, it is proved that $r$ is not a lower bound of $A$. It follows from this that $\frac14$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$. In other words, $\inf A=\frac14$.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Since you mentioned why 1 is supremum , is my work on the supremum wrong?

Comment: No, but I think that my approach is shorter.

Comment: Good, thansk for the answer

Comment: Your answer on the infimum have some connection with Archimedes property ( or axiom)? I have a strong intuition that the answer is yes.

Comment: If you want to justify in detail that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+2n+1}{4n^2+2n}=\frac14$, you will need the Archimedean property.

Comment: I have another doubt regarding your answer. In a part of your proof, you write “ epsilon > r - 1/4”. After that, you write “ epsilon = r - 1/4”. I dont understand that, I am missing something?

Comment: It was a typo. I meant $\varepsilon=r-\frac14$ twice.

Comment: One question more : If we take r> 1/4, we have 1/4 < a < r. Therefore 1/4 is the greatest lower bound. That is the reasoning right?

Comment: I would say that, if we take $r>\frac14$, then there is some $a\in A$ such that $\frac14<a<r$, and therefore $r$ is not a lower bound of $A$. So, $\frac14$ is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Thanks. If f is a decreasing function, that means that F(n) < F(N) for N < n . If f(n) < r, how can conclude from that f(N) < r ? Or I am confusing things? Sorry for the cascade of questions.

Comment: At the point, I did not use at all the fact that $f$ is decreasing. I proved that $n\geqslant N\implies\frac{n^2+2n+3}{4n^2+2n}<r$, and then I applied this to $N$ itself; that is, $\frac{N^2+2N+3}{4N^2+2N}<r$.

Comment: Oh I see. Its a relevant part to apply that to N or the proof can finish at f(n) < r ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129192/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-udac).

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}
$
One useful characterization of the infimum is the $\varepsilon$-characterization. For $A \subseteq \Bbb R$, and $\a$ a known lower bound of $A$, then

$$\inf(A) = \a \iff (\forall \e > 0)(\exists x \in A)( \a < x < \a + e )$$

Essentially, if $\e > 0$, then you always capture some element of $A$ in $(\a,\a+\e)$.

That $x \to \infty \implies f(x) \to 1/4$ with $f(x)$ decreasing suggests that

$$\inf(A) = \frac 1 4$$

You should be able to use the above criterion to prove this.